# Record a range in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to insert data into Oracle about 'Acceptable ambient temperature range'. I can do it this way - create two fields:
`Acceptable minimum ambient temperature` and `Acceptable maximum ambient temperature`
But I'm interested is it possible to store the two values into one table row? Is there some appropriate table row type that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible to "store the two values into one table row".
Database relational management systems are all about storing multiple values per row!
One appropriate row "type" would be `(MIN_AAT integer, MAX_AAT integer)`

Perhaps you think about storing both values into a single column?

Comment: Well, on a second tought, temperature is not an integer: `create table TRANGES (MIN_AAT number, MAX_AAT number);`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see anything wrong with your first approach - storing min and max as separate columns. But if you feel you want it to be stored in one, you can always define your own object type - you can find many links online about custom types , for instance, http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm ; it's quite large topic to post it here.

Another way is to use XMLType (personally, I'd never use it in such case, but it's worth mentioning)

Comment: Nothing wrong with two columns at all. Asking for trouble to store two values in one column.

Comment: @David Aldridge : " asking for trouble" - absolutely agree , but it's what the question was about...